# How does a Content Security Policy help with preventing XSS and other injection vulnerabilities?

Tags: xss, content-security-policy

I was reading up on CSP's and I did some testing on a site which had one implemented, I found an xss vulnerability even though it was using a CSP.

Comment: CSPs are quite complicated, with many options for their use, and it is possible to leave "holes" in the defense both on purpose (which is often necessary) or on accident.  As a result, you're really just asking "How does a CSP work?" which is too broad of a question for this site.  I would suggest doing some reading on CSPs in general, and then coming back and asking more specific questions if you have any remaining confusion.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include the CSP you are using, and the vulnerability you found, we might be able to explain what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Content security policy (CSP) has multiple directives, so it is possible to configure it such that images, frames, and multimedia are locked down, but JavaScript is wide open. So, depending on the exact policy, certain vulnerabilities may or may not be mitigated.

Without knowing more about the policy in question, it is hard to tell you exactly why it could be circumvented, but it is almost certainly due to the `unsafe-inline` [content source](https://content-security-policy.com/) for scripts:

`script-src 'unsafe-inline'`

This allows for inline JavaScript (e.g. script tags or HTML "on" event handlers). Thus, JavaScript can be injected onto the page, as if CSP isn't there at all.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common types of XSS attacks is a 'Stored XSS' attack.  Think of a site like StackExchange, where a user can enter a comment, then this comment is stored in a database, and served up to other users that visit the site.  Now, if a malicious user enters a specially-crafted 'comment' in the comment field, which includes <script> </script> tags, then the scripting between these tags may run in another user's web browser when that user browses to the page where the 'comment' is served.  See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Types_of_Cross-Site_Scripting for more info.

One way that a CSP can be used to help prevent this type of XSS attack is to use a strict content security policy that prohibits inline client-side scripting.  This requires all javascript and other client-side scripting to be in separate stand-alone files (i.e. .js files), and only client-side scripting in these files will be run in the browser; and any scripting that is included 'inline' in the same page with the HTML mark-up will not run.  This way, if the application serves up the malicious user's 'comment' in the HTML page, the malicious code will not run, because it is prevented from running by the CSP.

Having said that - there are many types of XSS attacks, and a CSP that is effective in preventing one type of XSS attack may not be effective in preventing other types of XSS attacks.  There is no 'magic bullet' to prevent all types of XSS attacks.  CSP can be used as another line of defense against XSS attacks, but CSP should not be thought of as a substitute for sound programming practices like sanitizing all external input, writing to the .Text attributes (instead of the .HTML attributes) of page elements whenever possible, etc.